# Setting up pg-pool connection on Next.js initialization: ERROR: "Can't resolve 'fs'

Tags: node.js, postgresql, next.js, node-pg-pool

I'm trying to use `npm pg` with [`pg-pool`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pg-pool) in my Next.js application.

I'm new to pooling connections but I gathered that I need to establish a pool connection whenever my Next.js server is initialized and I need to pass that connection as a module around my application.

From pg-pool docs:

> **a note on instances**
> The pool should be a **long-lived object** in your application. Generally you'll want to instantiate one pool when your app starts up and use the same instance of the pool throughout the lifetime of your application. If you are frequently creating a new pool within your code you likely don't have your pool initialization code in the correct place.

So, I created file `my-app/lib/db.js` to initialize my connection and hopefully pass that around my application whenever I need to run a query.

However, when I attempt to `import { Pool } from 'pg';` I get an error:
`Module not found: Can't resolve 'fs'`

[I found this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71106759/next-js-middleware-module-not-found-cant-resolve-fs) with the understanding now that..

> You can't use Node.js libraries that use fs in Next.js Middleware. Try using a client-side library instead.

So, my question is, how can I initiate a postgres-pool connection on a Next.js server node and route all queries through it? Do I need use a different package? Really not sure where to place this in the Next.js architecture.

Comment: Does this answer your question: [Can you keep a PostgreSQL connection alive from within a Next.js API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64093560/can-you-keep-a-postgresql-connection-alive-from-within-a-next-js-api)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only import it with "import { Pool } from 'pg';" in a component (not an API route) without calling the "Pool" object inside "getServerSideProps" or "getStaticProps" it will fail because Nextjs will include the "Pool" object in the client bundle and this way you will try to import a server-side module "fs" in the browser.

If you call the "Pool" in "getServerSideProps" or "getStaticProps" Nextjs will know NOT to include the "Pool" object in the client bundle and the problem will be solved.

There is a very good explanation here: https://maikelveen.com/blog/how-to-solve-module-not-found-cant-resolve-fs-in-nextjs

Comment: Thanks, I searched forever and somehow didn't see that article. I ended up reworking this one on MongoDB https://awesomenextjs.com/articles/nextjs-mongodb